# WordPress archive.php не выводит записи кастомной таксономи/категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть кастомный post type и таксономия категорий для этого типа записи:

```
function kgzb_create_articles_research() {

$labels = array(
    'name'               => __( 'Server news', 'kgzb-theme' ),
    'singular_name'      => __( 'Server news', 'kgzb-theme' ),
    'add_new'            => __( 'Add New', 'kgzb-theme' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Post', 'kgzb-theme' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Post', 'kgzb-theme' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Post', 'kgzb-theme' ),
    'view_item'          => '',
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Post', 'gdl_back_office' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'Nothing found', 'kgzb-theme' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in Trash', 'kgzb-theme' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    //'menu_name'          => __( 'Server news', 'kgzb-theme' )
);

$args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'public'              => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    "show_in_nav_menus"   => false,
    'has_archive'         => true,  // <- MD
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'server-news', 'with_front' => false )
);

register_post_type( 'server-news', $args );

register_taxonomy(
    "server-news-category", array( "server-news" ), array(
    "hierarchical"      => true,
    "label"             => __( 'Categories' ),
    "singular_label"    => __( 'Categories' ),
    "show_in_nav_menus" => false,
    "rewrite"           => true
) );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'server-news-category', 'server-news' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'kgzb_create_articles_research' );
```

По сути, мне нужно чтобы было три шаблона типа записи, которые я могу редактировать:

1. Блог, арихв постов
2. Страница таксономии поста/категории
3. Страница одной записи

При этом, шаблоны 1 и 2 должны отличатся.

Изначально я сделал два шаблона:
archive-server-news.php и single-server-news.php

Сейчас я сделал просто шаблон archive.php и в нём:

```
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                    while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_post(); ?>
                        <?php
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'server-news' ); ?>
                    <?php endwhile;
                endif;
```

Но теперь при переходе на страницу категории не выводит никаких записей, хотя они подвязаны под таксономи.

Делал провреку на is_tax и менял сам цикл have_post, не помогло(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для taxonomy другая иерархия шаблонов

- taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
- taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
- tag-{slug}.php
- tag-{id}.php
- category-{slug}.php
- category-{ID}.php

Попробуйте шаблон taxonomy-server-news-category.php для таксономии

Подробнее тут https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/